# Question About Similarity Solution Method

Tags: functions, partial-differential-equations, transformation, nonlinear-dynamics

The similarity solution method is supposed to be able to solve at least some nonlinear partial differential equations, in addition to linear ones.  After playing around in Mathematica to find a nonlinear PDE that can be solved, I found that the general solution to $u_t^{2} = u_{xx}$ is $u = c_1(t + x) + c_2(t - x)$, where $c_1$ and $c_2$ are arbitrary functions of $t + x$ and $t - x$ respectively. So I decided to try this problem.

Using the scaling transformations $x \to px$, $t \to qt$, and $u \to ru$, I assume that $u(x,\ t)$ and $ru(px,qt)$ are similar solutions.  Plugging these scaling transformations into the PDE, I get

$$\left(\frac{r}{q} u_t \right)^2 = \frac{r}{p^2} u_{xx}$$

and thus $p^2 ru_t^{2} = q^2 u_{xx}$.  To be arithmetically consistent with the original PDE, it should be the case that $q = \pm p \sqrt r$, and thus the similarity solution is $ru(px,\pm p \sqrt rt)$. In turn, choosing $p = \frac{1}{x}$ yields $ru \left(\pm \frac{\sqrt rt}{x}\right)$.

1. At this point, do I have to proceed with the plus and minus cases as two separate branches of the problem, or can I choose which branch to use and arrive at the same solution in either case?
2. If I choose (or start with) the plus case, $ru\left(\frac{\sqrt rt}{x}\right)$, I can make the substitutions $v = \frac{\sqrt rt}{x}$ and $f = ru$, and plug $f(v)$ into the original PDE.  However, the resulting ODE

$$\frac{d^2 f}{dv^2} + \frac{2}{v}\frac{df}{dv} = \frac{r}{v^2} \left(\frac{df}{dv} \right)^2$$

contains the scaling factor $r$.  This has not happened for the linear PDEs I have solved using this method.  Can I choose $r$ at will to be any function of $v$ which simplifies the ODE as much as possible, or do I have to solve for $r$ in some way?

Comment: 1. You can choose either branch. Your PDE contains second derivatives and squares, meaning that the negative branch and the positive branch yield the same result. 2. The value of $r$ can be chosen arbitrarily. The whole point of the scaling is that the problem remains invariant for any choice of $r \in \mathbb{R}$, so you can choose it freely.